# Remove Circle From Google Map V3

Tags: javascript, google-maps

I want to remove a circle from a google map.

Anyone up to drop me that little piece of code on how to just remove
the circle?

Comment: Probably not :) You will need to specify what kind of element it is you want to hide/remove.

Answer (score 0):

It's using simple setMap as null. This might be helpful: http://enbake.com/remove-circle-polygons-from-google-map-api-v3